# NUL symbol gets inserted anywhere in the XML

Tags: xml, oracle, character

I am using Oracle 11g and when I query data from database manually, it looks ok. But when I view it using Notepad++, there is a special character that gets inserted anywhere in the xml produced. Please see image below:

[image]

I tried everything and deleted some parts of the xml, updated the db and query again but the invalid character just differ in location. Any idea is much appreciated, thanks!

Best regards,

Racs

Comment: More information is needed. How was the XML file generated? Notepad++ is probably right in showing “NUL”, but how did it get there? NUL is invalid both in XML 1.0 and in XML 1.1, so a program that generates such XML is seriously broken.

Comment: @Jukka <br/> Hi Jukka, <br/> thanks for the comment. The XML file was generated using this query: SELECT CODE,  sys.xmlType.getClobVal(profilexml) profileClob, LASTMODIFIEDDATETIME from PROFILE, ProfileSearchIndex where Profile.id = ProfileSearchIndex.ProfileId and profileSearchIndex.SEARCHCODE = 'USER' and profileSearchIndex.SEARCHVALUE1 = UPPER(?). Note that we are using Oracle 11g. I found that this invalid character only shows up when the profilexml saved in DB is more than 4000 characters long. By the way, the profilexml saved is using XMLType as its type. Thanks a lot!